# При клике на карту не появляется адрес

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Копирую код в среду разработки все как там https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/ добавлю свой api ключ. Карта работает, но при клике так и не появляется адрес определенного места.
Возможно ли что-то еще нужно добавить?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что Вам нужно подключить jQuery. 
Или если уже подключен, просмотреть последовательность загрузки скриптов.

Comment: Подключил jQuery, после скрипта с api ключом. Результат такой же как и был. Возможно еще нужны json?

Comment: Без ссылки на вашу тестовую страницу или примера кода например на jsfiddle мы не сможем угадать, где допущена ошибка. А в случае проблем с ключом надо вообще обращаться в поддержку Яндекс - они и проверят ключ, и подскажут, что на вашей странице сделано не так.

Comment: Спасибо всем). Разобрался.